# How to check pytorch 2.0 complied the model or not?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to use the new pytorch TorchDynamo to compile the model. I don't know if it complied properly and want to check before run `model.fit`. I did go through `torchdynamo` documentation. But I couldn't grasp the correct way to do it.

Please give me a module that can give me if the model is compiled or maybe a summary which has information about the compilation.

Also, please correct me if I have the wrong understanding. `torch.compile`